# JSON DeserializeObject Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

When I deserialize JSON to my class using Newtonsoft JSON.net, I get this error. What could be the cause of it ? Certainly I am missing something obvious..

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type

Here is my JSON:

```
[
  {
"AgreementUID": "a8ea9f59-82f3-4799-b684-06a2cd95d9a1",
"ProjectUID": "851D12CE-7DC3-E511-9C58-F0DEF17C096F",
"year": "2016",
"data": [
  {
    "month": 1,
    "B": "4",
    "P": "1",
    "F": "1"
  },
  {
    "month": 2,
    "B": "",
    "P": "",
    "F": ""
  }
  ]
 }
]
```

Here is my Class:

```
public class AgreementBreakdownObject
{
    public string AgreementUID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectUID { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
    public List<AgreementBreakdownDataObject> data { get; set; }
}
public class AgreementBreakdownDataObject
{
    public int month { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string P { get; set; }
    public string F { get; set; }
}
```

I do deserialize like this:

```
string jsonData = hData.Value;
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AgreementBreakdownObject>> (jsonData);
```

Please suggest what is my mistake here. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to escape your quotes if the json is within a C# string. Example below:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class AgreementBreakdownObject
    {
        public string AgreementUID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectUID { get; set; }
        public string year { get; set; }
        public List<AgreementBreakdownDataObject> data { get; set; }
    }
    public class AgreementBreakdownDataObject
    {
        public int month { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
        public string P { get; set; }
        public string F { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AgreementBreakdownObject>>(@"[
  {
""AgreementUID"": ""a8ea9f59-82f3-4799-b684-06a2cd95d9a1"",
""ProjectUID"": ""851D12CE-7DC3-E511-9C58-F0DEF17C096F"",
""year"": ""2016"",
""data"": [
  {
    ""month"": 1,
    ""B"": ""4"",
    ""P"": ""1"",
    ""F"": ""1""
  },
  {
    ""month"": 2,
    ""B"": """",
    ""P"": """",
    ""F"": """"
  }
  ]
 }
]");
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant excerpt [from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#regular-and-verbatim-string-literals):

> Use verbatim strings for convenience and better readability when the string text contains backslash characters, for example in file paths. Because verbatim strings preserve new line characters as part of the string text, they can be used to initialize multiline strings. Use double quotation marks to embed a quotation mark inside a verbatim string.